# How to treat \x00 as simple hexastring with 00 (double zero)?

Tags: c++, c

```cpp
char a[] = "\x02\x00\x0C\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x03";
```

I want to pass this char to some function by ignoring `\x00` as a null termination so it treats it as hexastring with `00` not null termination. Is it possible in c?

this function in which im passing it is a kind of testbed where it will get it as
02000c0800000 ...43 like this.

Comment: Sure. Just print out each `char` value, one at a time. Begin with `std::cout << a[0];` and move on from there.

Answer (score 3):

If your question is how to pass this around ergonomically, you can use a container that supports character sequences that include nulls.

One such container is `std::string`:

```cpp
char a[] = "\x02\x00\x0C\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x03";

const std::string s(std::begin(a), std::end(a));
```

In C++17, `std::string_view` is another convenient way to pass this around:

```
const std::string_view sv{a, std::distance(std::begin(a), std::end(a))};
```

You could also use `std::vector<char>` in a similar way (not shown).

If your question is how to print hexadecimal values, including for null, you could use try something like this:

```cpp
char a[] = "\x02\x00\x0C\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x03";

std::cout << std::hex << std::uppercase << std::setfill('0');
std::for_each(std::begin(a), std::end(a), 
              [](const char c) 
              {  
                  std::cout << "\\x" << std::setw(2) << static_cast<int>(c); 
              });
```

Output is this, which looks like your original string:

```
\x02\x00\x0C\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x03\x00
```

Comment: you can simply use the [`sv` suffix](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/operator%22%22sv): `std::string_view a{"\x02\x00\x0C\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x03"sv}`

Comment: how can I do it in C, if all I have to do it in char* and to pass it into a function which takes it as a char *.

Comment: @SurajRathore it’s still not clear what you want to do. Print the string?  If you pass a char pointer to a function, the function _must_ take a length as well, since it can’t use null as a sentinel.

Comment: char a[] = "\x02\x00\x0C\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x03";
I want to pass this char to some function by ignoring \x00 as a null termination so it treats it as hexastring with 00 not null termination. Is it possible in c?

this function in which I'm passing it is a kind of testbed where it will get it as 02000c0800000 ... like this.

Comment: @SurajRathore Just do that. It will work just fine. If it doesn't, show us the code that doesn't work and we'll fix it for you.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Is right:  just try something and show us where you’re stuck. As I wrote above, you’ll need to pass a pointer and a length. Otherwise, how can this function distinguish between `"\x02\x00\x0C\x08\x00"` and `"\x02\x00\x0C\x08\x00\x00"`?  The `std::string_view` class contains just such a pointer and a length, and provides many convenient member functions to work with the character sequence.